# decompiler code Error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, null

can somebody help me out to fix this code. There is a compilation error with`$SwitchMap$uk$ac$aber$dcs$blockmotion$gui$Direction` and `InputMismatchException` what should I write instead?

Below is the entire function. If somebody could give me a brief explanation to let me understand what's going on I would really appreciate it.

```
 private void setSlideNumber(String msg, Direction direction) {

    boolean tryAgain = true;

    do {
        System.out.println(msg);

        try {
            int ime = Math.abs(this.in.nextInt());
            switch(null.$SwitchMap$uk$ac$aber$dcs$blockmotion$gui$Direction[direction.ordinal()]) {
                case 1:
                    this.slideHorizontalLeftNum = -ime;
                    ((SlideTransformer)this.slideHorizontallyLeftTransformer).setAmount(this.slideHorizontalLeftNum);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    this.slideHorizontalRightNum = ime;
                    ((SlideTransformer)this.slideHorizontallyRightTransformer).setAmount(this.slideHorizontalRightNum);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    this.slideVerticalUpNum = -ime;
                    ((SlideTransformer)this.slideVerticallyUpTransformer).setAmount(this.slideVerticalUpNum);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    this.slideVerticalDownNum = ime;
                    ((SlideTransformer)this.slideVerticallyDownTransformer).setAmount(this.slideVerticalDownNum);
            }

            tryAgain = false;
        } catch (InputMismatchException var8) {
            System.out.println("Please type a valid number");
        } finally {
            this.in.nextLine();
        }
    } while(tryAgain);

}
```

By the way, `Direction` is an enum

and this is the class for  Slide transformer

```
public abstract class SlideTransformer implements Transformer {
    int amount;

    public SlideTransformer(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return this.amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

Now the code of the Enum Direction:

```
public enum Direction {
    LEFT,
    RIGHT,
    UP,
    DOWN;

    private Direction() {
    }
}
```

Comment: What is that null.$SwitchMap$uk$ac$aber$dcs$blockmotion$gui$Direction

Comment: What is the error for `InputMismatchException`?

Comment: From where did you get the idea that `null.$SwitchMap$uk$ac$aber$dcs$blockmotion$gui$Direction[direction.ordinal()]` would be correct Java?

Comment: I got it from the .class and I need it to make it work in the actual .java
`null.$SwitchMap$uk$ac$aber$dcs$blockmotion$gui$Direction` and `uk/ac/aber/dcs/bloockmotion/gui` makes reference to the package `Direction` makes reference to the enum within the package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your weird piece of code comes from a class decompilation.

The `switch` is made on the `Direction` enum's ordinal value, so just replace :

```
switch(null.$SwitchMap$uk$ac$aber$dcs$blockmotion$gui$Direction[direction.ordinal()])
```

with

```
switch(direction.ordinal())
```

Note that we usually `switch` directly on the enum, and use its different values, it is far more straightforward :

```
switch(direction){

    case LEFT :...
    case RIGHT : ...
    ...

}
```